# App reject because of Non-public API "countOfEntities"

Tags: ios, objective-c, appstore-approval, magicalrecord

I have uploaded an app which uses MagicalRecords Library, in that they have defined method `+ (NSUInteger) countOfEntities;` in MagicalRecordShortHand.h file and I have called this method in my code. We can called it as MR_countOfEntities. I have replaced it with MR_.

Here my question is that will apple still reject if there is defined method in MagicalRecordShortHand.h?

Please guild me if anyone have knows about it.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  and/or the store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change the name completely? Also, whenever your app is rejected for a similar reason and you are SURE that you are not calling a private api, but you are calling your own method that has (by chance) the same name, just reply to the review team and explain this. They will understand and your app would (usually) be approved.